# What's the official site for Malaysia's e-visa?

Tags: malaysia, e-visas

I'm and Indian citizen, and am planning to go to Malaysia as a Tourist.

What's the official site for applying for the e-visa? A google search leads me to several sites, none of which seem to be the official one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of agents available online. However, http://www.windowmalaysia.my/ is the Official Visa Channel and eVisa Operator for the Government of Malaysia as stated here: https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/visa/evisa.html.

I have used windowmalaysia myself and got the eNTRI right away. The website is a little buggy but a tad bit cheaper. You don't need an e-visa and eNTRI is sufficient if you are visiting Malaysia for less than 15 days.

> eNTRI Note is valid for a single journey into Malaysia for up to a maximum of 15 days for tourism
>   purposes only.

Comment: Also, there are much restrictions on eNTRI like transit Airports and not visiting countries before arriving in Malaysia. So, its important to read the conditions through.